# Create table with TEXTIMAGE_ON for LOB DATA in different filegroup

Tags: sql-server

I have created a new filegroup to keep LOB DATA. I wanted to check if it's better to keep table on PRIMARY filegroup and keep LOB Data on different filegroup with TEXTIMAGE_ON or keep table on a filegroup for LOB data

for example, create t1 on primary filegroup and LOB Data on separate filegroup(LOB_Filegroup)   or create table T1 on filegroup for LOB data(LOB_FILEGROUP) and LOB DATA on a flegroup(LOB_FileGroup)

I would like to know if there any performance impact based on table storage design.

```
Create TABLE T1
( 
column1 int not null PK,
Column2_XML Varchar(max) null,
Column3_XML Varchar(max) null,
Column4 varchanr(20) null,
Column5 datetime not null,
column6 datetime not null
) 
ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [LOB_DATA_Filegroup]


Create TABLE T1
( 
column1 int not null PK,
Column2_XML Varchar(max) null,
Column3_XML Varchar(max) null,
Column4 varchanr(20) null,
Column5 datetime not null,
column6 datetime not null
) 
ON [LOB_DATA_Filegroup] TEXTIMAGE_ON [LOB_DATA_Filegroup]
```